# SVN repository broken on Windows after using colon

Tags: windows, svn

we are using svn in a multi OS environment. I made the mistake to commit a file containing a colon, i.e. `bar:foo` and `baa:foo`. Under linux this is ofcourse not a problem but under Windows `:` is not an allowed character for the file system. After realizing my mistake a renamed the files from linux using `svn mv`.

The problem is that svn on Windows is stuck when ever a version containing the `:` is checked out. Consider the following procedure:

1. checkout the repository on its latest state (i.e. with fixed filenames)
2. Checkout a commit containing the filenames with colon. This leads to the following:

> Added foo
>
> Skipped obstructing working copy foo
>
> Warning! One or more files are in a conflicting state.`

3. Now trying to go back to the corrected version with `svn co` gives the error:

> Error 'bar:foo'  is not a valid filename in directory Folder`

4. Didn't work try again `svn co`:

> Error The XML response contains invalid XML
>
> Error Malformed XML: no element found`

Now the repository is stuck, i.e. no more checkout is possible as you will always get the last error. Note that this creates a file `foo` which is not in the repository. I tried to remove the file and/or use `svn cleanup`. But without any success as the file is always restored before `svn` tries to perform the actuall update.

Is there a way to fix the local svn?
Or is the only way to make a new checkout and to avoid the affected revisions under Windows at all cost?

Answer (score 3):

So I figured out a way of fixing it. The basic idea is to update to the latest revison but only the directory itself, but not the files within the directory. Thisway all files are removed and not tried to be updated/ restored. Now the directory is on the right revision and we can get the remaining files of the current revision as well.

Using tortois svn:

1. Go to the affected diretcotry
2. Update to revision...

   1. Select latest revision
   2. Select Update Depth "only this item"
   3. Press Ok
3. Update to revision...

   1. Select latest revision
   2. Select Update Depth "Fully recursive"
   3. Press Ok

Comment: Fantastic. Saved my life 3 years later. Thanks!